# Should i synchronize my "fake-time" class methods?

Tags: java, time, synchronized

Im creating a "Fake-time" or TimeSource for my application, the point is that this new class should control the application's actual time. This means all the methods that uses Date() constructor, System.currentTimeInMillis(), or Calendar.getInstance(), should instead use my class (ex. TimeSource.getInstance.getCurrentTimeInMillis()).

This way i can manipulate the system's actual time when in a testing environment.

But i wonder if i should synchronize these methods, or how i should to it.

I can show you the following code:

```
public class DateTime {

private static final long ONE_MINUTE = 60 * 1000;
private static final long ONE_HOUR = ONE_MINUTE * 60;
private static final long ONE_DAY = ONE_HOUR * 24;
private static final long ONE_MONTH = ONE_DAY * 30;
private static final long ONE_YEAR =  ONE_DAY * 364;

private static DateTime instance;

private Date date;
private Date staticDate;

private boolean isStatic = false;

private long addedTimeInMilliseconds = 0;

public static DateTime getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DateTime();
    }
    return instance;
}

private DateTime() {
    date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    staticDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
}

public Date getCurrentTime() {
    if (isStatic) {
        return staticDate;
    } else {
        date.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis()+this.addedTimeInMilliseconds);
        return date;
    }
}

public long getCurrentTimeInMillis() {
    if (isStatic) {
        return staticDate.getTime();
    } else {
        return System.currentTimeMillis()+this.addedTimeInMilliseconds;
    }
}

}
```

Ive run some tests on the methods - both single and multithread tests - and the performance with syncronized methods is alot worse than without the synchronized. Problem is that im unsure if the methods might make problems in the future if i do not synchronize them.

I also use a few methods to add to the "current application's time"

```
public void addMinutesToDateTime(int minutes) {
     this.addedTimeInMilliseconds += (minutes * ONE_MINUTE);
 }
```

So im asking a little advice, or knowledge about synchronized, and weather or not i should use it on my methods.

Best regards - Martin.

Comment: You might want to rethink some of the design of this class - by returning the actual Date instance you are storing as state, you make it possible for other code to do something like `DateTime. getCurrentTime().setTime(...)`

Comment: @mattb Good point, thanks for the input

Comment: There was actually a comment about eager initialization on the singleton pattern (dunno why it was deleted) - and the guy was correct i guess, cuz it makes the class thread-safe - hence no need to synchronize anything.

So i guess thats what im gonna do instead of doing synchronized or volatile stuff.

Comment: Eager initialization only makes the class thread safe if you aren't allowing other classes to mutate state in the singleton instance. Based on the code sample you posted, getCurrentTime() mutates the state.

Comment: @mattb Okay, thanks for the info :) I will scratch the getCurrentTime() method.

Comment: @mattb So lets say i got a staticDate in my class, as above, will a setStaticDate(Date date); method also ruin the thread safety?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have only one thread updating the time and make the fields `volatile` if needed.

I wouldn't use `Date` in a mutable way, I would use `long`.

Comment: About the date vs. long issue, do you mean the same as mattb in the comment above? Should i just scratch the method that returns a Date object? Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks a bunch. An eager initialization of the singleton pattern i use, cleared the thread-safe issue. So i guess its all good now :)

Thanks again!

Comment: scratch the method that returns a Date or return a new Date instance on each call.